# SSE(Server sent events) меньше грузит MySQL чем long polling?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, sse

Делаю уведомления на сайте. Как работает SSE на сервере? Он как и long polling каждый раз дергает БД, или вешает ивент, и, когда кто-то изменяет БД, только тогда проверяет изменения и отдает на страницу?

js:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

php(сервер):

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$query=mysqli_query($link, "запрос");
$notif=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo  "data:{$notif['text']}\n\n";
```

Websocket меньше напрягает БД чем long polling потому что когда что-то заносим в БД отправляем это-же в скрипт websocket и он рассылает всем соединениям, а с SSE как ?

Comment: Вы должны также понимать, что каждый запущенный инстанс php жрет до 128-256Мб (в зависимости от настроек в php.ini) оперативной памяти. Оставляя инстанс открытым после отдачи страницы, есть риск повесить сервак фантомными инстансами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко - **нет**. SSE не грузит MySQL, это ваш php алгоритм грузит базу.

Для SSE нужно:

- Тип данных `text/event-stream`
- Бесконечный цикл с логикой

Пример:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

  while(true) {
    $query=mysqli_query($link, "запрос");
    $notif=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo  "data:{$notif['text']}\n\n";
  }
```

Да это легче чем ajax запросы. SSE работает примитивно, открывает постоянное соединение (пока сервер отвечает), в котором php скрипт дёргает базу **постоянно**. Это в корне не правильное решение. *Но опять таки, можно сделать более лёгкий алгоритм, чтобы не дёргать базу постоянно.*

Но всё же для этого есть прекрасное решение в виде websocket, о которых вы говорите.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал изменять сообщения в БД не перезагружая страницу. Изменяется вывод на странице. При том в PHP файле не цикл, а один запрос как в моем коде выше. Выходит что, каждый раз когда идет обращение  со страницы, выполняется код php на сервере? Для чего цикл тогда?

Comment: @Hertz бесконечный цикл обязательно должен быть. Скорее всего sse закрывает соединение, потому что сервер перестал отвечать и заново его открывает, по факту сейчас у вас обычный Ajax. Это даже ещё хуже. Делайте websoket, это в разы оптимальнее.

Comment: Можно хоть для SSE, хоть для long polling в php не делать постоянно запросы в БД, а висеть скажем на ожидании на очереди Rabbit или какого нибудь другого MQ. И тогда скрипт будет просыпаться и отправлять данные когда появилось событие. Единственный минус по сравнению с WS в этом случае то, что на каждое соединение будет отдельный скрипт запущен, занимающий память